# Is there a way to disable typing for autocomplete? - Angular Material

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material

I have the following `autocomplete` in Angular material:

```
 <!-- Drop Down menu -->
          <mat-form-field>
            <input placeholder="Select one" [matAutocomplete]="auto" matInput>

            <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
              <mat-option value="Cars">Cars</mat-option>
              <mat-option value="Books">Books</mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
          </mat-form-field>
```

Is there a way to disable typing on the `input` so that the user does not defeat the purpose of the dropdown menu? Right now, the user can just type something instead of picking an option, or even edit an option when selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the user to input anything in the input but instead only select from a list, why don't use a mat-select? The user can also select with the keyboard, typing what he needs. The docs: https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview

Answer (score 11):

Yes there is

Here is the documentation with an example to disable the autocomplete input

https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples

I needed to disable the input after a selection and I couldn't use a mat-select because I had over 600 options... so the autocomplete / typeahead was needed. Can't use mat-chips either because only one selection can be picked at one time.

stackblitz = https://stackblitz.com/angular/kopovlnpxapb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-overview-example.ts

Comment: the stackblitz is not working, keeps loading forever

Answer (score 2):

You have to put `readonly` on the input.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. To do so, in the `ngOnit` function, disable the reactive form control for that field:

```
this.myControl.disable()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can set maxlength="0", and options are still possible to be selected.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want input field to disable all the time then use normal select drop down
2. If you want to use auto complete but don't want user to edit selected option in input field then you might wanna use chips autocomplete - https://material.angular.io/components/chips/examples